# Running two Angular apps simultaneously

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm working on an application, and want to extend/expand it with another (new) Angular application. The goal is to eventually replace the old one by the new one, but for now, it should just be accessible by going to /v2, and serve as a pilot.

The setup is as follows:

- NodeJS backend: port 11020
- Angular/AngularJS-hybrid app: port 11000
- **Angular-app: port 4200 (this is the new application)**

I want to be able to access the new application by going to **my-app.com/v2**.

---

I have created a `proxy.conf.json` file for the main application:

```
{
  ...
  "/v2": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4200/",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

I think it works, because when I go to the /v2 route, it indeed forwards me to the new application, and when using 'Inspect Element' I see the new index.html's head, body and page title. Ok, great.

But.. it never loads the application any further, and throws the following error:

```
app.ts:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at app.ts:8
    at Object.iN1H (app.ts:39)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    ...
```

---

The error is thrown both locally using webpack-server, and after building/serving from our server.

The error points to the original (hybrid) application, where `angular` is used to reference angularjs.

**Why is the *new* application crashing because of references in/to the *old* application**?

Comment: You’ll have to let Angular know in what directory it runs. You can do that by setting the base href. https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag

Comment: @MikeOne Yes, I have done that, as `<base href="/v2">`, and the application is built in the dist/public/v2 directory.